# how to read sms otp in xamarin. forms webview with local html

Tags: javascript, html, xamarin.forms

i have xamarin.forms webview project with local html file. and one of html file is for otp verification with one input field. is there any way to read device sms otp through xamarin and put that otp in webview html input field.

Answer (score 0):

so to read sms's you're likely going to write native dependency services to for iOS/Android to natively read sms's on the device. Have a look at this documentation here [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

For the web view you can execute some js inside the web view using C#, using code similar to below.

```
await webView.EvaluateJavascriptAsync("document.getElementById('myText').value = 'Johnny Bravo';)
```

So this code will allow you to execute some js inside your web view.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in iOS12, you can refer to [this page](http://It%20is%20possible%20in%20iOS12,%20you%20can%20refer%20to%20this:https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/using-ios-12-otp-security-code-autofill-in-xamarin-forms/) for the details.

And [this](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2019/03/09/using-sms-retriever-api-in-xamarin-android/) is Android related.